# error C2664: 'CSchemaString::CSchemaString(LPCTSTR)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'LPCTSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2005

I am getting the following error:

error C2664: 'CSchemaString::CSchemaString(LPCTSTR)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'LPCTSTR'

for the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<=tComponent.GetUpperBound();i++)
{       
    CSchemaString temp(i); // LINE AT WHICH ERROR OCCURS
    XComponent = ((Component *)tComponent.GetAt(i))->GetXMLCode(FOR_SAVING);               //AddName(*/temp +":"+*/ ((Component *)tComponent.GetAt(i))->GetName());
    XSave.AddPlant_Item(XComponent);

}
```

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED.

Comment: What is the type of `XComponent`? On which line do you get the error? What's the prototype of `XSave::AddPlant_Item`?

Comment: Just a guess, but does the `CSchemaString` ctor expect a `char*` or some other kind of string? You give it `i`, which I'm guessing is some kind of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to create `temp` as a `CSchemaString` passing `i` (which appears to be an `int`) as the parameter. If I've got it correct, possible constructors for this class are:

```
CSchemaString ()
CSchemaString (const tstring sValue)
CSchemaString (const TCHAR *szValue)
CSchemaString (const double nValue)
CSchemaString (const CSchemaType &rOther)
```

Depending on what you're doing, maybe you need to convert `i` to a string or double to meet with the `CSchemaString`  constructor signature?